# Set value of disabled input from jQuery for ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Trying to figure out how to set input's value inside JavaScript *and* make sure it is posted to the server in ASP.NET. It has to be *disabled* field too.

I tried this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DriverIdTextBox" runat="server" enabled="false" />
```

And then in jQuery:

```
$("*[id$='DriverIdTextBox']").val("JAVA");
```

This when posted doesn't give me "JAVA" on backend.
When I enable textbox - I get this value on server just fine. I tried to enable control and disable on clientside like so:

```
$("*[id$='DriverIdTextBox']").val("JAVA").prop("disabled", true);
```

Same problem - value is not posted to server.

Basically I want to set read-only label/input whatever so user can read it but at the same time I want to post it to server when user submits form. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried giving the tag and empty value="" attribute for jquery to fill?

Comment: I would also try using $('#DriverIdTextBox').val("JAVA"); for the jquery selector.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Selector you suggest won't work, it is ASP.NET - ID's get converted when page generated

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="DriverIdTextBox" runat="server" enabled="false" name="DriverIdTextBox" value=""/>

Comment: I'm not sure what it will change. Selector works. This is not my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not post back to the server if you've got the textbox disabled.

Set a label to the value of the textbox and set a hidden field to the value as well.

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnDriverId" runat="server" />
 <asp:Label ID="lblhdnDriverId" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

    this.lblhdnDriverId.Text = "";
    this.hdnDriverId.Value = "";

$("*[id$='lblhdnDriverId']").val("JAVA");
$("*[id$='hdnDriverId']").val("JAVA");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the element to readonly instead of disabled to get the values posted to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it's value like this

```
   this.Request.Form[DriverIdTextBox.ClientId]
```

Disabled elements do not get submitted with the form,you must remove "disabled" atrribute before post back

Comment: This is not my problem. What I have works. Problem is that value I see displayed on a screen is not posted to server. Only when enabled.

Comment: this.Request.Form[DriverIdTextBox.ClientId] returns NULL

Comment: Sorry,disabled elements do not get submitted with the form... you should remove "disabled" atrribute before post back