# asp.net text doesn't send value when disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to enable and disable the text box using jQuery, which works fine. The disabled text box has value in it. But the issue I am facing is that, the disabled textbox doesn't pass value to server.When I enable it using jQuery, I see text box value in code behind (Debugging mode). Any ideas why this is happening or alternative approach to get value from disabled textbox in code behind.

HTML:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtUniqueNo" runat="server" onkeyup = "OnChange(this)" required/>
```

Javascript that i use to disable in view page

```
var inputBox = $("#<%=txtUniqueNo.ClientID%>");
inputBox.prop('disabled', true);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason is simple, *disabled* inputs values aren't submitted to the server due to web-browsers submission limitation policy.

The *W3* spec says that input tags that are *disabled* are considered invalid and should not be submitted.

Instead, use the `readonly` attribute:

```
<input type="text" readonly />
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$("#<%=txtUniqueNo.ClientID%>").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

UPDATE:

Look how to remove the `readonly` attribute if needed: http://jsfiddle.net/ynevet/84HrM/

Comment: Thanks this did the job.. i am getting value in code behind,, how to remove attribute readonly from textbox.. i am using   inputBox.removeAttr('readonly');   is this correct?

Comment: To also change the background, like in disabled mode, please add: txtBox.style.backgroundColor = "#EBEBE4";

Answer (score 3):

> It will not post back to the server if you've got the textbox disabled.
>
> Set a label to the value of the textbox and set a hidden field to the value as well.

[ref from :](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15858130/3559224)

### We will do it by using few  way's

- Disable the `textbox` after the values sent to the server side( or enable the `textbox` and send values finally `disable` the `textbox`)

---

- store the `textbox` values to  any other controls with the control(`span`) should be hide and get the hided control(`span`) values to send server side  '

---

- You can use `Hidden field` for store text box values for send the values to server side...

---

- Or use `readonly` attribute  instead of enable and disable attribute

---

Comment: Thanks. readonly attribute did my job although your info is useful did upvote

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Enable attribute, try using disabled in style when you want to disabled and change the attribute value when you want to enable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputBox = $("#<%=txtUniqueNo.ClientID%>");
inputBox.prop('readonly', true);
```

or

```
inputBox.prop('readonly', false);
```

now server can read value of text box

Answer (score 0):

enable before submitting through javascript/jquery and again disable from server again.

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?