# Not getting Input text value in code behind

Tags: html, asp.net, input

I want to use the value of the `textbox` which is input `html` in one of my query. SO I tried like below

```
string strInwardNO = Request.Form["TxtIwNo"];
```

and HTML is

```
<input id="TxtIwNo" type="text" runat="server" disabled="disabled" />
```

but I am not getting value. What is wrong here

**When I check while debugging, I always get it as NULL**

Comment: `Disabled` doesn't send the value of the control to the server side. Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308124/asp-net-text-doesnt-sends-value-when-disabled

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl: I was guessing it, but `readonly` will change the lookout of the textbox

Comment: if your input is disabled, then how it hold any user value? and if it not has any user values then set default value at your back end..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to input field value was posted to your backend it cannot be disabled. Change it to readonly and style it to look like disabled:

```
input[readonly] { 
    background: #CCC; 
    color: #333; 
    border: 1px solid #666 
}
```