# How to get Textbox.Text if Textbox ReadOnly = true?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code

```
protected void ReadData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string content = input_content.Text;
  ...
}
```

I get the value as long as the Textbox isn't ReadOnly or Disabled.
So for ReadOnly or Disabled I tried

```
input_content.ReadOnly = false;
input_content.Enabled = true;
string content = input_content.Text;
```

but this does not work, the value would be "".
How can I access the value when the Textbox has one of the properties?

Cheers

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308124/asp-net-text-doesnt-sends-value-when-disabled

Comment: not really, I already use readonly but it wont work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the the asp Textbox to a simple input with readonly.
Now it works, without disabling readonly or else.

I don't know why this is different, but at least it works.